# Why is there a discrepancy between the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix (PCA) and the eigenvalues of the kernel matrix (kernel PCA)?

Tags: pca, kernel-trick, eigenvalues, matrix-decomposition

I've done PCA on my data matrix $ \mathbf{X} $ which gives me i.a. the eigenvalues $ \lambda $ and eigenvectors $ v $ of the data covariance matrix $ C=\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} $. I'm now extending my analysis to also apply kernel PCA. Now, it can be shown that the eigenvalues of $ C $ should be equal to the eigenvalues of the kernel matrix $ \mathbf{K} $:
$$
\mathbf{K} \alpha = \lambda \alpha \\
\Leftrightarrow \mathbf{X} \mathbf{X}^T \alpha=\lambda \alpha \\
\Rightarrow \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{X}^T \alpha=\lambda \mathbf{X}^T \alpha \\
\Leftrightarrow Cv=\lambda v
$$

With $ \alpha $ being the eigenvector of $ \mathbf{K} $ and $ v:= \mathbf{X}^T \alpha $ being the eigenvector of $ C $.

After applying kernel PCA with a *linear* kernel (equivalent to "standard" PCA), however, the eigenvalues are **not** equal. I see, however, a (maybe general) relationship between $ \lambda_{PCA} $ and $ \lambda_{KPCA} $, because $ \overline{\lambda}_{PCA, i} = \overline{\lambda}_{KPCA, i} $ with $ \overline{\lambda}_i = \frac{\lambda_i}{\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k} $ for the $ i $-th of the $ n $ eigenvalues.

So why are the eigenvalues not equal? I'm using Python with `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` and `sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA`.

Comment: Assuming the data are centered, the covariance matrix is $\frac{1}{n} X^T X$, not $X^T X$ as you've written. This means the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix would be a constant factor of $\frac{1}{n}$ times those of the $X^T X$ (and also $X X^T)$. Does this match the discrepancy you see?

Comment: I forgot the factor $ \frac{1}{n} $ for both $ C $ and $ K $, but the result is the same, the eigenvalues _should_ be equal. But I noticed, that the Gram / kernel matrix $ K $ doesn't get scaled by $ \frac{1}{n} $ while the covariance matrix _does_ get scaled. This was the issue. Now, after scaling the KPCA eigenvalues there is just some minor discrepancies, which probably result from numerical issues I suppose. Thanks!

Comment: I realized, that the scaling of the kernel matrix eigenvalues has to be done via $ \frac{1}{n-1} $. Then, the eigenvalues are exactly equal.

Comment: Glad it worked. If the scaling factor is $\frac{1}{n-1}$ the unbiased covariance matrix estimator is being used.

Answer (score 1):

The covariance matrix $ C $ as well as the Gram / kernel matrix $ \mathbf{K} $ have to be scaled by $ \frac{1}{n} $ with $ n $ being the number of samples in the data, assuming the data is centered:
$$ C = \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \\
\mathbf{K} = \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{X}^T $$
While the covariance matrix *does* get scaled in `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` (actually, PCA is computed via the SVD and the eigenvalues result from $ \lambda_i = \frac{S_i^2}{n-1} $ with $ S $ being the singular values), $ \mathbf{K} $ doesn't get scaled in `sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA`. After scaling the eigenvalues of $ \mathbf{K} $ manually by $ \frac{1}{n - 1} $, the descrepancy vanishes completely.